# Reset createBottomTabNavigator to initial tab on navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react navigation to implement this flow:

- Screen A (with a FlatList)

  - Screen B (createBottomTabNavigator, with 3 tabs)

    - Tab A
    - Tab B
    - Tab C

When an item is selected from flatlist user navigates to "Screen B", that contains detailed info about the item.

But, for example, if I select "Tab C" and then go back to "Screen A" and select another item, when I navigate to "Screen B" it will show "Tab C", i would like to aways show "Tab A" when I navigate to "Screen B".

Probably this behavior is because the createBottomTabNavigator is created only once. Maybe there is a way to reset to initial state, or select first tab programatically?

Comment: you can listen to route changes and dispatch actions yourself https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/screen-tracking.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SOLVED]:** I fixed it navigating directly to the desired tab `navigate('Tab A')` instead of going to Screen B `navigate('Screen B')`